# Checking if Collection contains an Object inside an Object

Tags: java

```
public class Address{
 private TypeAddress typeAddress;
 private String street;
 //Getters and Setters
 ...
}

public class TypeAddress{
  private String type;
  //Getters and Setters
  ...
}
```

I have a Collection of Addresses

```
Collection<Address> addresses = db.getAddresses();
```

I need to check if is there any address of a type that the costumer will pick.
It's just pretending a situation so you guys will understand.

What I want is, I want to get the address of just one type, that type that the customer picked up. If he picked a type that does not exist, I'll pick another address.
So, I basically need to do 2 loops to check if is there any of its type, and if there is, I'll pick it on the next loop. If it's not, I'll pick another one on the next loop.
Is there a way to use the contains method of a Collection to check if the type of the address is what I want?

Something like:

```
if(addresses.contains("someType")){//remind that I'm trying to check not the object Address, but the object TypeAddress
 //get this address
}else{
 //get another address
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're forced to use a collection (and not a Map like suggested),  why can't you just iterate once and store the most "promising" instance as some Address reference:

```
Address address = null;
for (Address addr : addresses) {
    if ( isBetterThanAlreadyFound(addr, address) ) {
        address = addr;
    }
}


private static boolean isBetterThanAlreadyFound(Address addr, Address alreadyFound) {
    return alreadyFound == null || (addr.isOfDesiredType() && alreadyFound.isNot());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map<TypeAddress, Address>` so you can verify whether the necessary address exists and get it relatively fast and easy.

```
Map<TypeAddress, Address> addresses = new HashMap<TypeAddress, Address>();

//put something and then
TypeAddress type = getType();
Address address = addresses.get(type);
if (address != null) {
    return address;
} else {
   //do smth else
}
```

Don't forget to override methods `equals` and `hashCode` of class `TypeAddress` in a proper way.

Comment: I'm trying to reuse the code people from my project used, I really like Maps, I'll check if it's possible in this case to switch it for maps without crashing the whole project

Comment: This will only work if there will be one and only one of any given type in this map. Otherwise, there will be collisions on the keys and you won't get the data you intended to collect.

Comment: @dflems: do you really expect me to write absolutely working code in stackoverflow console? It there's this option with multiple addresses, then we should use `Map<TypeAddress, Set<Address>>` with all necessary code enhancements. Or, better, `Multimap` from guava.

Answer (score 0):

even contains internally do the looping logic , use Map instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for a way to break out of a loop, or a way to continue at the beginning of the loop.  Conveniently enough, they're called `break` and `continue`

```
for (Address address : addresses) {
    if (!address.getType.equals("someType")) continue;
    myAddress = address;
}
```

OR

```
for (Address address : addresses) {
    if (address.getType.equals("someType")) {
        myAddress = address;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache CollectionUtils API :

```
Predicate p = new Predicate()
{
 public boolean evaluate(Object o)
 {
   return ((Adress) o).getTypeAddress().getType().equals(TYPE_INPUTED_BY_USER);
 }
}

return CollectionUtils.exists(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I found an example in a book:
// e.g.
Shape shape;
if (shape instanceof Circle) {  
//check if there is any class object Circle in  
// the collection shape
// take some action
}
```